# Sequelize one to many association trying to pull foreign key from the wrong table

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm getting an error with Sequelize association for a simple one to many. The foreign key should be from the Answer model but for some reason its trying to pull the foreign key from the Client model. Not exactly sure why its doing that

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "clients" ("id","account_id","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id","account_id","room_id","createdAt","updatedAt","student_id";
Error
    at Query.run (/home/an/Desktop/GA/unit3/dynamic_polling_backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:50:25)

  parent: error: column "student_id" does not exist
```

My 2 models

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Client extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            Client.hasMany(models.Answer, {
                foreignKey: 'student_id',
                as: 'answerers',
            })
        }
    }
    Client.init(
        {
            account_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            room_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'Client',
            tableName: 'clients',
        }
    )
    return Client
}
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Answer extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            Answer.belongsTo(models.Client, {
                as: 'answerer',
                foreignKey: 'student_id',
            })
        }
    }
    Answer.init(
        {
            student_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            question_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            response: DataTypes.TEXT,
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'Answer',
            tableName: 'answers',
        }
    )
    return Answer
}
```

Comment: The ```foreignKey``` association is to be made in ```Answer``` model. The Client model association should be as ```Client.hasMany(models.Answer, {as: 'answerers' })```

Comment: @vicky If association should have a custom `foreignKey` option then it should be indicated in both pared associations (hasMany/belongsTo). So that's not the case.

Comment: @An Nguyen please show how you insert `Client` record

Answer (score 0):

It turns out its because it was referenced with a wrong fk from a completely differnt model.